Can't print string (char *) to VGA memory
I'm writing my own OS kernel and got started on print functions using C++. I can print to VGA memory (0xB8000) with chars just fine, but when I use my print_str(const char* str) function it just prints three random symbols onto the screen (no matter the size and value of the string it print the same three random symbols):

A random symbol I can't describe
A square root symbol
A smiley face.

These are my print_char and print_str functions:
void print_char(const char character) {
    Char* buffer = reinterpret_cast<Char*>(VGA_ADDRESS);
    
    // Handeling new line character input
    if(character == '\n') {
        print_newline();

        return;
    }

    if(col >= NUM_COLS) {
        print_newline();
    }

    buffer[col + NUM_COLS * row] = {static_cast<uint8_t>(character), color};
    col++; // Incrementing character number on this line
}


// Printing string to the screen
void print_str(const char* str) {
    // Calling the print_char function the same amount of times as the strings length
    for(size_t i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        print_char(str[i]);
    }
}

And my linker script if needed:
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386)

ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    /* Bootloader section at 0x7C00 (BIOS loads the bootloader here) */
    . = 0x7C00;

    .boot : {
        *(.boot)      /* Include all .boot sections */
        *(.text)      /* Include all .text sections for bootloader code */
    }

    /* Align to 1 MiB (where kernel starts) */
    . = 0x100000;

    /* Kernel sections */
    .text : ALIGN(4096)
    {
        __kernel_start = .;  /* This is the start address of the kernel */
        *(.text)
    }

    .rodata : ALIGN(4096)
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }

    .data : ALIGN(4096)
    {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss : ALIGN(4096)
    {
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
    }

    __kernel_end = .;  /* This is the end address of the kernel */
}


What is Char? Looks like some custom type that expects two values, character and color. And you are doing reinterpret_cast with this custom type?

"I can print to VGA memory (0xB8000) with chars just fine." Can you show the code that works?

The print_char prints the char on itself. "Char" is a struct that has two uint8_t variables: character and color. And yes im using reinterept cast on it.

Are you familiar with the code page 437 character set?  Square root is 0xFB, and smiley face is either 0x01 or 0x02.  The indescribable character is harder to pin down.

The first one is 0xE8 the second is 0xFB and the third is 0x01

Are you sure your bootloader read the ENTIRE kernel from disk? Is it possible the number of sectors you read doesn't cover the size of your kernel?

I think the problem is likely not in the code you show, but somewhere else. Do you have a project in GIthub or somewhere else?  I asked about reading enough sectors because a string literal will be placed in the .rodata section and I wonder if defining a string literal added an .rodata section to your kernel which increased the kernel size to the point where the string you want to print isn't loaded in memory.

https://github.com/HoniT/myProjects/tree/main/IoOS-test The only thing that ive changed is that i removed extern c from the print functions

Your bootloader is hardcoded to read 8 sectors, i.e. 4K bytes.  Since .rodata and .data are aligned to 4K bytes, they will definitely not be loaded.

Also you define KERNEL_LOAD_SEG as 0x1000 but then you use it as an offset, not a segment (with 0 as the segment in ES).  So you're loading at linear address 0x1000, not 0x10000 as you may think.  The code works because you do it consistently, but since the bootloader itself is at linear address 0x7c00, you will overwrite it if your kernel is larger than about 25 KB.

There are other problems with the code besides the number of sectors. The linker script (+Make file and boot.asm) needs work as the location on disk of anything above 0x100000 is not correct. Your string won't be loaded properly at all.

I have sent a pull request on Github ( https://github.com/HoniT/myProjects/pull/1 ) with a series of changes that should fix many issues and should allow your kernel to work as expected. The file differences can be seen here: https://github.com/HoniT/myProjects/pull/1/files

The memory of VGA text-mode consists of 16 bits, or 2 bytes, per character. A standard c/c++ char is 8 bits, or 1 byte. A character in VGA text-mode is laid out with a byte containing special information like the foreground colour, background colour, and whether the character is blinking. After this byte, there is a byte for the character. This means a standard char can not be used to write on a vga text-mode buffer.
You can read more on Wikipedia on VGA text mode. The OSDev Wiki also has a great article on vga.

The 2-bytes-per-cell layout of VGA text mode is presumably why there's a Char struct -- and why the code is using it.

@cHao I'll go on record that the use of a structure called Char  by the OP actually confused me at first as I read it as char and thought it was a single byte as well. I'd probably recommend the OP rename it to something like Text_cell or something that wouldn't be easily confused with char
